# Is it possible to add Schedule Start Date Time and Schedule End Date Time using ConTrigger?

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

Im trying add  add Schedule Start Date Time and Schedule End Date Time using ConTrigger is this possible in Quartz.net ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is supported by the CronTrigger. CronTriggerImpl has a constructor that allows you to do this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a <see cref="CronTriggerImpl" /> with fire time dictated by the
/// <param name="cronExpression" /> resolved with respect to the specified
/// <param name="timeZone" /> occurring from the <see cref="startTimeUtc" /> until
/// the given <paran name="endTimeUtc" />.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">The name of the <see cref="ITrigger" /></param>
/// <param name="group">The group of the <see cref="ITrigger" /></param>
/// <param name="jobName">name of the <see cref="IJobDetail" /> executed on firetime</param>
/// <param name="jobGroup">Group of the <see cref="IJobDetail" /> executed on firetime</param>
/// <param name="startTimeUtc">A <see cref="DateTimeOffset" /> set to the earliest time for the  <see cref="ITrigger" /> to start firing.</param>
/// <param name="endTime">A <see cref="DateTimeOffset" /> set to the time for the <see cref="ITrigger" /> to quit repeat firing.</param>
public CronTriggerImpl(string name, string group, string jobName,
    string jobGroup, DateTimeOffset startTimeUtc, 
    DateTimeOffset? endTime,
    string cronExpression, 
    TimeZoneInfo timeZone) : base(name, group, jobName, jobGroup)
{
    CronExpressionString = cronExpression;

    if (startTimeUtc == DateTimeOffset.MinValue)
    {
        startTimeUtc = SystemTime.UtcNow();
    }
    StartTimeUtc = startTimeUtc;

    if (endTime.HasValue)
    {
        EndTimeUtc = endTime;
    }
    if (timeZone == null)
    {
        timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local;
    }
    else
    {
        TimeZone = timeZone;
    }
}
```